# Nginx configure SSL load balancer

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, gitlab

I have a Docker Server where I have installed **GitLab** from [sameersbn/docker-gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab)

I have a nginx container that listen to 443:433 and 80:80, I will use this one to load balance HTTP and HTTPs (with signed cert) requests

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    upstream gitlab {
        server gitlab:10080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.domain.tld;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate         /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /git/ {
            proxy_pass http://gitlab;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

Without SSL, working url to acces gitlab is http://www.domain.tld:10080/git

With SSL, I want the url to be https://www.domain.tld/git

**Using this nginx load balancer configuration**

When I go on http://www.domain.tld/git

```
400 Bad Request

The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

When i go on https://www.domain.tld/git

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

These are my first signed certificate, how is this supposed to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem there are 2 steps required:

1. make Nginx redirect HTTP to HTTPS
2. Make Gitlab to listen port
   80 via HTTP

Why to make Gitlab to listen port 80? This technique called SSL offload that prevent redundant HTTPS encryption/decryption to happen between upstream and web-server. It is rarely required and only makes sense in case of different hosts with complex security requirements.

**Nginx**

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    www.domain.tld;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen         443 ssl;
   server_name    www.domain.tld;

   [....]
```

}

**Gitlab**

```
vi ./gitlab/config.yml
gitlab_url: "http://server1.example.com" # http rather than https
```